# How to identify the message we send

Tags: android, sms

In android, how to identify the message we sent. The address field in the `content://sms/` table always show the number to which we send or the number which we receive the message from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the column "type".  type == 1 is message was received; type == 2 message was sent.